# Change value to 0 if outside certain range

Tags: r

I want any ET values outside of my desired range to be 0 (or NA) and I think it should be this simple:

```
df[df$ET < 0 & df$ET > 10,]<- 0
```

but

```
 Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*`, daysum$ET < 0, , value = 0) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

Even simplifying it without the `&`, I get the same error.

```
str(df):

'data.frame':   365 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ day     : Factor w/ 367 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Rain_Tot: num  0 0 0.254 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ET      : num  0.776 0.529 0.432 0.458 0.435 ...
```

Comment: Same error message when I tried both.  Maybe something is wrong with my dataframe?

Comment: There are a lot of NAs, which I guess is what is meant by "missing values are not allowed".  Any way to get around that?

Comment: Please show `str(df)`

Comment: Now that I think of it, how on earth `df$ET < 0` and at the same time `df$ET > 10`??? If that could be possible, we should fire all our math professors at once.

Comment: @Nazer, I don't think there's anything wrong with your `data.frame`. Be sure you're just selecting the relevant column and that there aren't any commas between your `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
df$ET[df$ET < 0 | df$ET > 10] <- 0
```

Demonstration:

```
## Sample data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ET = c(-5, 1, -6, 2, NA,
                        10, 11, NA, 3, 4),
                 V1 = 0)
df
#    ET V1
# 1  -5  0
# 2   1  0
# 3  -6  0
# 4   2  0
# 5  NA  0
# 6  10  0
# 7  11  0
# 8  NA  0
# 9   3  0
# 10  4  0
```

Try the following out to see what they do:

```
df$ET < 0
df$ET > 10
df$ET < 0 & df$ET > 10
df$ET < 0 | df$ET > 10
```

Using that info, you can use:

```
df$ET[df$ET < 0 | df$ET > 10] <- 0
```

Resulting in:

```
df
#    ET V1
# 1   0  0
# 2   1  0
# 3   0  0
# 4   2  0
# 5  NA  0
# 6  10  0
# 7   0  0
# 8  NA  0
# 9   3  0
# 10  4  0
```

Comment: When I try "the following" that you suggest, I get TRUE and FALSES and with the final line, the same error.

Comment: @Nazer, Please paste ***exactly*** what you do as the final line.

Comment: I did forget part of it!  The `$ET` after the first df.  It is solved and we have a very nice filtering example!  Thanks, Ananda.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the NAs you have, because the following worked on some test data I had:

```
df[df$ET < 0 & df$ET > 10]<- 0
```

(Without the comma)